In a base change of a scheme of finite type to a field extension, is the image of an irreducible component an irreducible component?
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a field $k$, and let $L$ be a field extension. If $A$ is an irreducible component of $X \times_k L$, is $\pi_1(A)$ an irreducible component of $X$?
The image of an irreducible set is irreducible, so the only issue is to check maximality. I think we have to use surjectivity of the morphism, as well as possibly the dimensions of those irreducible components.
Suppose $\pi_1(A)$ is not irreducible, and let $B$ be the irreducible component that $\pi_1(A)$ is in. By taking $B$ with its reduced scheme structure and replacing $X$ with $B$ and $X \times_k L$ with $B \times_k L$ which has a closed immersion to the original $X \times_k L$, we can reduce to when $B$ is reduced. Then, (Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, 12.2.M), every irreducible component of $B \times_k L$ has the same dimension as $B$.
I then want to use surjectivity to somehow conclude that $dim(\pi_1(A)) = dim(B)$. But I don't know if $A \ra B$ is surjective. I only know that $B \times_k L \ra B$ is surjctive.

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04KX
